# Emacs with Slime and Swank for non-leiningen projects

Tags: emacs, clojure, slime, swank

I found [this website](http://riddell.us/ClojureSwankLeiningenWithEmacsOnLinux.html) which explains how to use emacs with leiningen, swank, and slime. Is there a way to use slime + swank in non-leiningen projects i.e. how can I connect to slime/swank repl to run a ad-hoc Clojure script while I write it as [demonstrated here](http://vimeo.com/2419596)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `swank-clojure.jar` in `CLASSPATH` and your script should have following code:

```
(require 'swank.swank) 
(swank.swank/start-repl 4005)
```

to start swank process on port `4005` (or some other)...

P.S. You can look onto Incanter's [swank](https://github.com/liebke/incanter/blob/master/script/swank) script, that pass this code in environment variable, and later it evaluated as part of [boostrap script](https://github.com/liebke/incanter/blob/master/script/run.clj)